# Regex to match "path/*.extension"

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to find a regular expression that would match the following format:

```
path/*.file_extension
```

For example:

```
temp/*.jpg
usr/*.pdf
var/lib/myLib.so
tmp/
```

Using the regex, I want to store the matching parts into a String array, such as:

```
String[] tokens;
// regex magic here
String path = tokens[0];
String filename = tokens[1];
String extension = tokens[2];
```

In case of the last case `tmp/`, that contains no filename and extension, then token[1] and token[2] would be null.
In case of the:
    `usr/*.pdf`
then the token[1] would contain only the string `"*"`.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried?

Comment: Is input like `usr/*` or `usr/*.*` possible?

Comment: @Pshemo, yes definitely.

Comment: Thank you all for your contributions! It is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use Java7 then you can use named groups like this

```
String data = "temp/*.jpg, usr/*.pdf, var/lib/*.so, tmp/*, usr/*, usr/*.*";

Pattern p = Pattern
        .compile("(?<path>(\\w+/)+)((?<name>\\w+|[*]))?([.](?<extension>\\w+|[*]))?");

Matcher m = p.matcher(data);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("data=" + m.group());
    System.out.println("path=" + m.group("path"));
    System.out.println("name=" + m.group("name"));
    System.out.println("extension=" + m.group("extension"));
    System.out.println("------------");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should wotk:

```
String line = "var/lib/myLib.so";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.+?(?=/[^/]*$))/([^.]+)\\.(.+)$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
if (m.find()) {
    for (int i=1; i <= m.groupCount(); i++) {
        tokens.add(m.group(i));
    }
}
System.out.println("Tokens => " + tokens);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Tokens => [var/lib, myLib, so]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using Java.  This should work:

`Pattern.compile("path/(.*?)(?:\\.(file_extension))?");`

Comment: Maybe pass the flag `Pattern.DOT_ALL`.  Newlines are allowed in filenames in most major OSes, so there's no reason to match file names with non-newline spaces but fail to match file names with newlines.

Answer (score 0):

On a different approach, a simple usage of 'substring()/lastIndexOf()' methods should serve the purpose:

```
    String filePath = "var/lib/myLib.so";
    String fileName = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    String path = filePath.substring(0, filePath.lastIndexOf('/'));
    String fileName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf('.'));
    String extension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.')+1);
```

Please Note: You need to handle the alternate scenarios e.g. file path without extension.

Answer (score 0):

Why use a regular expression?
I personally find `lastIndexOf` more readable.

```
String path;
String filename;
@Nullable String extension;

// Look for the last slash
int lastSlash = fullPath.lastIndexOf('/');
// Look for the last dot after the last slash
int lastDot = fullPath.lastIndexOf('.', lastSlash + 1);
if (lastDot < 0) {
  filename = fullPath.substring(lastSlash + 1);
  // If there is no dot, then there is no extension which
  // is distinct from the empty extension in "foo/bar."
  extension = null;
} else {
  filename = fullPath.substring(lastSlash + 1, lastDot);
  extension = fullPath.substring(lastDot + 1); 
}
```